# Method in C to check longest matching string?

Tags: c, search, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

For example,

I have a string: 7364jruf62

I also have a dynamic 2d array: (7, 4f6, 73, 2)

I need to go through the string and find the longest matching string from the array (7 from the string can match with 7 from the array but 73 would be a better match since that's 2 digits). Then move on to the rest of the string to try find matches from the array, (since 73 was the best match we now search through 64jruf62 in the string).

The reason for the array being dynamic is so I can add the matching value for the string at the end.

I have attempted to do this in a loop with

```
for (i = 1; i <= numberOfStrsInArray; i++) {
            count = 0;
            shift = 0;
    while (string[shift] == array[i][count]) {
                    shift++;
                    count++;
```

However, this does not work and instead the program crashes because of this line. Could anybody tell me why this causes my program to crash or propose a better solution for what I'm attempting to do? Thanks. I can provide more code from my program if the fragment I provided is not clear.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.* Show a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with char arrays here, it would be easier to work with `strstr` rather than compare by one.

```
int index index = -1;
int maxLength = -1;
for (i = 1; i <= numberOfStrsInArray; i++) {
   if (null != strstr(string, array)) {
          if ((strlen(array) > maxLength) {
             index = i; 
             maxLength = strlen(array);
   }
}
```

As @Jongware mentioned, in case the array doEs not contain null-terminated stings - it will lead to crash since the array will be out of bounds. If you absolutely must use non null-teminated strings, you should consider using something like this

```
int size = sizeof array / sizeof array[0];
char * strA = new char[ size + 1);
strncpy (strA, string, size);
strA[size] = 0;
```

Comment: The "dynamic 2d array" may not contain a proper C string. Perhaps OP can clarify that.

Comment: Well if it's not null-terminated than author's code will surely crash (and it does, actually), since it will try to compare beyond the array bounds.

Comment: (After your last addition) Perhaps the other way around is better: use [`memcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcmp) to search. Limit the amount of memory to `strlen(string)-maxlength` - well, something like that. Still hoping the OP comes back with more clarifications, by the way.

Comment: Agree, memcmp would be much better.

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

```
for (i = 1; i <= numberOfStrsInArray; i++)
```

> 1) here, `i` should start from `0`. As you know the array index always start from `0`. So the first string would be at `0` index.
>
> 2) Another point is the loop should run till `numberOfStrsInArray-1`.

Therefore, the loop should change to

```
for (i = 0; i < numberOfStrsInArray; i++)
```

**Edited**

> According to the comment by the OP, the 2nd point above is only relevant to the code then..

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for not mentioning this. The first string in the array has to be an empty value so I simply skipped over it.

Comment: @yezi3 you omitted all the important code from the question. Why?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The bit of code I provided is my main method of searching and comparing characters and is the part of my program that's causing it to crash.

Comment: You omitted most of the code. We've no idea what any of the variables are. Try harder. Don't make us guess. Don't conceal code. Don't be lazy. Make a [mcve]. Don't compare strings with `==`. Use `strcmp`.